# TemplateDoesNotExist but it exists

Tags: django

I have created a template following the django book example as the next:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/search/" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My views is:

```
def search_form(request):
    return render_to_response(request, 'search_form.html')
```

and my settings:

```
import os
RUTA_PROYECTO = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(RUTA_PROYECTO ,'templates'),)
```

It should work but when I run the sever i get the TemplateDoesNotExist

Comment: Try setting `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(RUTA_PROYECTO ,'templates'),)`. Note the comma.

Comment: yeah thx it is an error but i fixed it and the TemplateDoesNotExist continues

Comment: Show the project structrue.

Comment: Here you are a screenshot of my directory tree http://prntscr.com/2i6w55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(RUTA_PROYECTO ,'templates'),)
```

Use TEMPLATE_DIRS when you want to store template in some location outside your project folder.

Change

```
def search_form(request):
    return render_to_response(request, 'search_form.html')
```

To

```
def search_form(request):
    return render_to_response(request, 'mywebsite/search_form.html')
```

You have to specify what app's template you want to pull. Otherwise two different apps with the same template name won't work. If you specify a TEMPLATE_DIRS, it will be probed if Django can't find the requested template in that app folder.